# jquery not running in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I write this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo3').skdslider({delay:1000, animationSpeed: 5000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'sliding'});
});
```

This works fine in Mozilla and chrome but gives error in IE.But when i change

```
JQuery(document).ready(function(){          
    $('#demo3').skdslider({delay:1000, animationSpeed: 5000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'sliding'}); 
});
```

this works in IE, but not works in Mozilla and chrome.

Please tell me what should i do?
error is in IE:-

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'skdslider'

test site link:-
http://ots.netau.net/

Comment: try using at the top var $=JQuery

Comment: if `JQuery` works (with uppercase J), and not `$`, and it's only on IE, you need to get the gremlins out of your computer ?

Comment: I tried var $=JQuery but it fails

Comment: Will you please explain what you want to say?

Comment: It sounds like jQuery is working in IE, and it's the SKDSlider plugin that is not working. How are you including these scripts on your page?

Comment: whatever that skdslider is, its probably defined in another js file. are you sure you link it correctly? check both IE and mozilla developer consoles and see what errors you get. also adeneo is right, if JQuery with uppercase J works for you, then youve done some hell of a job redefining the fabrics of the universe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
  ;
  (function($, document, undefined) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
     /// YOUR CODE HERE
     });
  })(jQuery, document);
```

Btw, jQuery is written with small J, but i suppose that was a typo...

Comment: you are genius. i modify your code with 

$(function($, document, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    /// YOUR CODE HERE
  $('#demo3').skdslider({delay:1000, animationSpeed: 5000,showNextPrev:true,showPlayButton:true,autoSlide:true,animationType:'sliding'});

    });
 });  and this works.  Thanks buddy

Comment: Consider accepting this as a correct answer them ;) Am glad I could help!